# How to diagnose why Wolfram Alpha page locks up Chrome and IE?

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer-9, wolfram-alpha

This evening a page at [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/entities/calculators/binomial_distribution_confidence_interval/w1/63/o4/) is causing both Chrome and IE to become unresponsive.

i've tried looking at the F12 tools of both browsers, and find nothing unusual that would indicate what the browser is busy doing.

How can i diagnose what on the page is causing browsers to lock up?

[image]

[image]

Both Profiler tools for Chrome and IE are unable to be "stopped" and report the problem.